# Fractional Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fa.functional-analysis

Let $T: L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the Fourier transform. Is there any reasonable definition of fractional Fourier transform (i.e. operator $A$ such that $A^{\alpha}=T$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$), and if there is, is it of any use?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform ?

Comment: Voting to close as "just ask Google or Wikipedia" (and lack of background motivation other than natural curiosity)